# Angular-6 How to run build files on browser and auto-detect changes when angular2-cli app files get changed?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I am running angular2-cli app and trying to run build files on browser for view and when files are changed, these build files should auto-detect changes and update changes and view on browser automatically like a watcher?

How to achieve that?

I have used below command:-

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer --watch
```

After creating build files, how to display view using these build files and auto-detect changes when files in app get changed and corresponding view should update?

I am deploying dist files using

```
 npm install http-server -g
```

`http-server ./dist` .

However, any changes in angular-app is not updated.

### Error when file changed and saved:-

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

    [4880:000002362A3E0200]  3073977 ms: Mark-sweep 1313.4 (1441.8) -> 1313.4 (1441.8) MB, 1912.2 / 0.1 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


    <--- JS stacktrace --->

    ==== JS stack trace =========================================

    Security context: 0000029E02FA54D9 <JSObject>
        2: /* anonymous */ [0000002EF25822D1 <undefined>:~5461] [pc=000001803821AEBC](this=0000033F46320061 <JSFunction base54 (sfi = 000003E0C2B4A539)>,str=0000009E2323E039 <Very long string[2687906]>,delta=1)
        3: /* anonymous */ [0000002EF25822D1 <undefined>:5430] [bytecode=000002BED7ECCD79 offset=83](this=0000026E50826AC9 <AST_Toplevel map =
    000002DAD9648199>,options=0000008766ACE9C9 <Object...

    FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
     1: node::DecodeWrite
     2: node_module_register
     3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
     4: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
     5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString
     6: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint
     7: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts
     8: v8::internal::AsmJsScanner::IsNumberStart
     9: 

000001803

56043C1
```

Comment: `ng serve` is that what you need?

Comment: Use `ng serve` rather than `ng build`. [ng serve](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve)

Comment: ng serve does not write files in dist folder and when app files changed and saved does not update it in dist folder as well as view on browser.

Comment: May I know, why you want to server file from Dist during development?

Answer (score 0):

You can't watch files after the ng build. if you want to keep editing while testing your app, just use ng serve -o

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error is related to the heap memory..

Increasing the memory can solve this issue..

Anyway I post the build command and configuration in angular.json as well for detailed reference..

FYI: I verified this process in angular 6.

`"prod-build-ui-now": "node --max_old_space_size=2048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --deploy-url /_assets/angular/project_name/ --output-path dist/project_name/ --prod --project project_name --watch"`

Here **--watch** is plays the main role.

**--max_old_space_size=2048** will take care of heap out of memory issue.. If you still face the issue just increase the value 1024 to that.

**--prod** will take the prod configuration in your angular.json.

`"production": {
    "optimization": false,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": false,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "fileReplacements": [
        {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    ]
}`

The above configuration will make sure you will get your latest updates by quickly.